# Show Toolbar in Internet Explorer Pop-ups

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-8

I know that its possible to open a "bare" (e.g. no toolbars) popup window using Javascript. I also know that other browsers, such as Chrome, allow the user to override the developer's preference and display the toolbar on these popup windows. Is there any such functionality in Internet Explorer 8?